# At least one of two fields must be completed validation

Tags: javascript, validation

First of all, I am **not** using jquery validation plugin.

I have the following validation in JavaScript:

```
var m = mob.substr(0,2);
var l = land.substr(0,2);

if (mob == '' && land == '') {
    alert("You must enter at least one phone number");
    return false;
}
else if (mob.length != 10 || m != "04") {
    alert("Mobile number is invalid. Must be a valid australian mobile number.");
    return false;
}
else if (land.length != 10 || l == "04" || l == "01" || l == "05" || l == "06" || l == "09" || l == "00") {
    alert("Landline is invalid. Must be a valid australian landline number.");
    return false;
}
```

As the title suggests, I want the user to be able to input just one or both of the fields but not leave both blank.

How can I incorporate this into the validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var m = mob.substr(0,2);
var l = land.substr(0,2);

if (mob === '' && land === '') {
    alert("You must enter at least one phone number");
    return false;
}
if (mob !== '' && (mob.length !== 10 || m !== "04")) {
    alert("Mobile number is invalid. Must be a valid australian mobile number.");
    return false;
}
if (land !== '' && (land.length !== 10 || l === "04" || l === "01" || l === "05" || l === "06" || l === "09" || l === "00")) {
    alert("Landline is invalid. Must be a valid australian landline number.");
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Here just add one more condition to the last two conditions. And make them as independent if statements. So all of them will be evaluated.

Comment: tried your answer and for some reason the console now says my function is not defined...?

Comment: Should be some scope issue. Can you post the code, including the caller code.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea...

```
function validate () {

    var sMobile = ...;
    var sLand   = ...;

    var lines = parsePhoneLines(sMobile, sLand);

    if (lines.errors) {
        for (var i = 0, length = lines.errors.length; i < length; i++) {
            alert (lines.errors[i]);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}

function parsePhoneLines (sMobile, sLand) {
    var mobile = parseMobile(sMobile),
        land   = parseLand(sLand);

    if (mobile.errors && land.errors) {
        return {
            errors: mobile.errors.concat(land.errors)
        };
    } else {
        return {
            land:   land.value,
            mobile: mobile.value
        };
    }
}

function parseMobile (s) {
    var errors = getErrorsForMobile(s);

    if (errors.length === 0) {
        return { value: s };
    } else {
        return { errors: errors };
    }
}

function parseLand (s) {
    var errors = getErrorsForLand(s);

    if (errors.length === 0) {
        return { value: s };
    } else {
        return { errors: errors };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var m = mob.substr(0,2);
var l = land.substr(0,2);

if (mob == '' && land == '') {
    alert("You must enter at least one phone number");
    return false;
} else {
    if (mob != '') {
    if (mob.length != 10 || m != "04") {
        alert("Mobile number is invalid. Must be a valid australian mobile number.");
        return false;
    }
    } else {
    if (land.length != 10 || l == "04" || l == "01" || l == "05" || l == "06" || l == "09" || l == "00") {
        alert("Landline is invalid. Must be a valid australian landline number.");
        return false;
    }
    }
}
return true;
```

Just need an else clause to the first if.

Answer (score 0):

```
var m = mob.substr(0,2);
var l = land.substr(0,2);
var flag=1;
if (mob == '' && land == '') {
    alert("You must enter at least one phone number");
    return false;
}
else if (mob.length != 10 || m != "04") {
    if(land.length>0)
     {
      //landline have value don not alert this
     }
     else
     {
        alert("Mobile number is invalid. Must be a valid australian mobile number.");
        flag=0;//means invalid
     }
}
else if (land.length != 10 || l == "04" || l == "01" || l == "05" || l == "06" || l == "09" || l == "00") {
    if(flag==1)
    {
        return true;// means mobile have value
    }
    alert("Landline is invalid. Must be a valid australian landline number.");
    return false;
}
```